# notifications not arriving ios 13.6

Tags: push-notification, notifications, cloudkit, subscription

Upgraded ios 13.6 and changed bundle identifier and container name. Created CKDatabaseSubscription for both public and shared database and can see in cloudkit dashboard. Both didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken get called in AppDelegate.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool{
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: { granted, error in
     
    guard granted else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      print("Registered for Remote notifications")
       
    }
  })
  return true
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data){
  let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
  let token = tokenParts.joined()
  print("Device Token: \(token)")
  })
  self.iCloudSubscribeToPrivateDB()
  self.iCloudSubscribeToSharedDB()
}
```

In the project both background fetch and remote notifications are enabled. I make databases changes in cloudkit dashboard, but push notifications are not being sent. I am working with iphone not simulator. They were working now just stopped after I made the above changes. What could be wrong?

Comment: Did everything get moved over to the new container? Could some things still be pointing to the default/old container?

Comment: I dont know where  it could be pointing to old container, I did global search on my project and replaced with new name. Also App ID refers to new container name in developer dashboard. I am getting some key chain errors in the meanwhile asking me to reconfirm with password  with allow action. Could that be causing it?

Comment: I just created a new container and it works. Don't know why the old container failed after I upgraded iOS